# Creating a string return value in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, octave

is there a way to create a function that return a `string`, and not a number, in `gnuplot`?

I get an error that a string returned instead of a number in ordinary functions like this:

```
func(x) = ((x eq "wow") ? "a" : "b")
```

Thanks

Comment: That works for me.  Can you show an example of it not working?

Comment: which version of gnuplot are you using?

Comment: Hey, 4.6 patch 3...
for some reason It works for me now also '~' .. I'll check my problems again... Thanks